# Creating pretty profiles in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I have been working with wordpress for a while now, but one aspect I never  tried, until now, is the rewrite  rules. I can create a profiles page  by using a template and catching a user's ID via GET, but I want to do something better.

That is, I want to rewrite the URLs to something like http://www.example.com/profiles/username

and this should hold for all the themes chosen. I think that's how Buddypress does it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To change the author base, add the following to your `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'init', 'so16194116_new_author_base' );
function so16194116_new_author_base()
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $author_slug = 'profiles';
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = $author_slug;
}
```

Visit the permalinks admin page after you implemented this, to flush the rewrite rules.

Comment: that's a good starting point. I can change the author.php  file with that and that  could actually do the  trick.